# Use Function to Create a Variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables

I am looking for a way to use a function to create a variable since I defined the variables I am using to create the variable inside the function independently depending on what the user does.

Here is what I have but it is not working:

```
var popupContent = ''
var message = ''
var postLink = ''
function createMessage() {
    popupContent = [
        "<p>" + message + "</p>",
        "<form action='" + postLink + "' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>",
            "<ul class='cd-buttons no_margin'>",
                "<li><a class='submit'>Yes</a></li>",
                "<li><a class='popup-close'>No</a></li>",
            "</ul>",
        "</form>",
        "<a class='cd-popup-close popup-close img-replace'>Close</a>"
    ].join('');
}

//Accept Employement Request
$('.popup1').on('click', function() {
    employeeName = $(this).siblings('.js-employee-name').text();
    var message = "Are you sure you want to hire <b>" + employeeName + "</b>?"
    var postLink = "/hire-employee"

    createMessage();

    $(".cd-popup-container").append(popupContent);
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/zdp5py7c/)

Comment: Can you be a bit more clear, which variable are you trying to initialize?

Comment: Not sure exactly what you're asking to do.

Comment: My problem is that when I call $(".cd-popup-container").append(popupContent); 

popupContent is still equal to ""

Comment: That doesn't appear to be possible, given your code. i suspect something else is going on.

Comment: How could I alter my code to make this possible?

Comment: That's not what i mean. The outcome you are describing is impossible. It isn't possible for `popupContent` to be empty when you append it to the container, given the code in your question. **This means the problem is caused by something you haven't included in the code above.**

Comment: My mistake. popupContent is not empty but this "<p>" + message + "</p>", does not appear.

Comment: Ah, well that's obvious. the `message` var you updated was a local one, rather than the one you defined outside. `var message` defines a new local message var that is completely separate from the one you defined outside.

Answer (score 4):

You could return the content from the function as follows and then just invoke the function within the `.append()` method:

```
function createMessage(message, postLink) {
    return [
        "<p>" + message + "</p>",
        "<form action='" + postLink + "' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>",
            "<ul class='cd-buttons no_margin'>",
                "<li><a class='submit'>Yes</a></li>",
                "<li><a class='popup-close'>No</a></li>",
            "</ul>",
        "</form>",
        "<a class='cd-popup-close popup-close img-replace'>Close</a>"
    ].join('');
}

//Accept Employement Request
$('.popup1').on('click', function() {
    employeeName = $(this).siblings('.js-employee-name').text();
    var message = "Are you sure you want to hire <b>" + employeeName + "</b>?"
    var postLink = "/hire-employee"
    $(".cd-popup-container").append( createMessage(message, postLink) );
});
```

**NOTE**
You want to pass the required data `message` and `postLink` as parameters to the function. **You do not need to declare or initialize these variables as global variables. You don't want to clutter the global scope. They are local to the callback and the data they hold would be passed to `createMessage()`. Please note that the variable `message` and `postLink` parameters of `createMessage()` are local to `createMessage()`.**

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fiddleyetu/zdp5py7c/1/)

Based on your demo, I wonder if it would not be more appropriate to use `.html()` instead of `.append()`!

Comment: This is much much cleaner.

Comment: This for some reason also returns nil, as if the function can not run correctly.

Comment: If you can create a demo, we would be glad to figure that out. Or please check the console for any errors. @Pabi, you have to pass data into the function as indicated above.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your code working - you need to define three Global varibles

1. popupContent
2. message
3. postLink

But Global var's are bad... So passing var's to your **createMessage()** is a good idea. And make it returning HTML too.

```js
function createMessage(msg, lnk) {
    return [
        "<p>" + msg + "</p>",
        "<form action='" + lnk + "' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>",
        "<ul class='cd-buttons no_margin'>",
        "<li><a class='submit'>Yes</a></li>",
        "<li><a class='popup-close'>No</a></li>",
        "</ul>",
        "</form>",
        "<a class='cd-popup-close popup-close img-replace'>Close</a>"].join('');
}

//Accept Employement Request
$('.popup1').on('click', function () {
    var employeeName = $(this).siblings('.js-employee-name').text(),
        message = "Are you sure you want to hire <b>" + employeeName + "</b>?",
        postLink = "/hire-employee";

    $(".cd-popup-container").append(createMessage(message, postLink));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="js-employee-name">John Doe</div>
<button class="popup1">Click Me!</button>
<div class="cd-popup-container"></div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to define it as a [**global variable**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/bzt2dkta(v=vs.94).aspx), in order to be able to set value in one function and use in another one.

**Note** : You don't need to use join for string concatenation. Simply use plus at the end of each.

```
var popupContent = ''
function createMessage() {
    popupContent = "<p>" + message + "</p>" +
        "<form action='" + postLink + "' method='post' accept-charset='utf-8'>" +
            "<ul class='cd-buttons no_margin'>" +
                "<li><a class='submit'>Yes</a></li>" +
                "<li><a class='popup-close'>No</a></li>" +
            "</ul>" +
        "</form>" +
        "<a class='cd-popup-close popup-close img-replace'>Close</a>";
}

//Accept Employement Request
$('.popup1').on('click', function() {
    employeeName = $(this).siblings('.js-employee-name').text();
    var message = "Are you sure you want to hire <b>" + employeeName + "</b>?"
    var postLink = "/hire-employee"

    createMessage();

    $(".cd-popup-container").append(popupContent);
});
```

**Another solution**, would be to use `return popupContent;` and `passMessage = createMessage();` to return data to the callee.

Comment: I think you got it right, but please fix the other *strange* codes, like the `join`.. and why not return the content instead of creating a global variable?

Comment: Also had to make message and postLink a global variable. Problem is that when I use popupContent in the click function, I get => ""